# Is it possible to add additional user defined properties other than standard properties in "keen" object?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, keen-io

As for every keen event, keen object gets automatically attached with structure of keen object.

```
var keen_event = {
 "keen": {
  "created_at": "2012-12-14T20:24:01.123000+00:00",
  "timestamp": "2012-12-14T20:24:01.123000+00:00",
  "id": "asd9fadifjaqw9asdfasdf939"
 },
 other properties...
}
```

But I want to add other custom properties in keen object as;

```
 {
 "keen": {
  "created_at": "2012-12-14T20:24:01.123000+00:00",
  "timestamp": "2012-12-14T20:24:01.123000+00:00",
  "id": "asd9fadifjaqw9asdfasdf939",
  "event_type" : "some_values",
  ...
 }
}
```

I tried adding other properties on keen and than encode the keen_event as:

```
var encodedData = base64.encode(JSON.stringify(keen_event));
```

The encoded data is then passed on keen api to create an event but I am getting error as : "Invalid property for keen namespace. You used: \'event_type\'".

Is there a solution for that? Is it possible to add custom key value properties other than standard properties on " keen" object while creating an keen event? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Obj.keen.prop=...`

Comment: I tried implementing but still does not work. I am getting error "Invalid property for keen namespace. You used: \'event_type\'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't allowed in the Keen API. The `keen` namespace is reserved and only a small handful of properties (such as `keen.timestamp` or `keen.addons`) may be specified in that namespace when an event is written. The namespace is reserved to allow Keen to add new special-purpose properties in the future and not worry about collisions with user-defined properties. (See also: https://keen.io/docs/api/#the-keen-object.)

Perhaps it's worth stepping back and asking: why do you want to add custom properties to the `keen` namespace? What would it allow you to do that you couldn't do with, say, `my.keen.x` or `keen_custom.x`?

FYI: I'm a platform engineer at Keen :)

Comment: I just wanted to add the custom properties in keen object because i wanted to add an additional id with name orig_id within keen object in additional to the id field and the orig_id value would be taken from the database i am using. 
Just wanted to know if its possible.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = {
 "keen": {
  "created_at": "2012-12-14T20:24:01.123000+00:00",
  "timestamp": "2012-12-14T20:24:01.123000+00:00",
  "id": "asd9fadifjaqw9asdfasdf939",
 },
 "keen1": {
  "created_at": "2012-12-14T20:24:01.123000+00:00",
  "timestamp": "2012-12-14T20:24:01.123000+00:00",
  "id": "asd9fadifjaqw9asdfasdf939",
 },
 "keen2": {
  "created_at": "2012-12-14T20:24:01.123000+00:00",
  "timestamp": "2012-12-14T20:24:01.123000+00:00",
  "id": "asd9fadifjaqw9asdfasdf939",
 }
}
var newObj = {}
Object.keys(data).map((element)=> {
  var t = {
    ...data[element],
    "event_type" : "some_values",
  }
 newObj[element] = t
 return element
})
console.log(newObj)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

This may help

Comment: The event_type has to be added for keen only not for keen1 and keen2.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
var keenEvent = {
 "keen": {
  "created_at": "2012-12-14T20:24:01.123000+00:00",
  "timestamp": "2012-12-14T20:24:01.123000+00:00",
  "id": "asd9fadifjaqw9asdfasdf939"
 }
};

keenEvent.keen.myNewProperty = "its value";
keenEvent.keen.myNewProperty2 = "its value2";
```

Comment: Doing it gonna get error "Invalid property for keen namespace. You used: \'event_type\'"

Comment: Do you use some kind of framework or Schema to validate the objects?

Comment: The object is encoded as:

 var encodedData = base64.encode(JSON.stringify(keen_event));

And further passed on keen_api to create an event.

Comment: And before applying that encoding, keen_event is a JavaScript object?

Comment: At that momento you should be able to add any property to the object. Maybe if can fails after because other checks

Comment: Yea it gets added on the keen object but when we encode the keen_object and call keen api than its creating the problem i guess. I am not sure if we can add custom fields on keen object of the event response.

Comment: So the problem is with the API, not with Node.js or JavaScript objects and properties I think

Comment: Even the api works well if we dont add any custom fields on keen object but in that case keen object will have the standard properties within it.

Comment: So thats why I was hoping to find the solution to include custom fields in keen object  on the response of keen_event